# Why I failed to execute a symlink of VLC program?

Tags: macos, vlc, symlink

I tried to execute VLC player from Terminal, so I built a symbolic link for VLC program. When I execute the symlink from Terminal, it do run the program but failed to open. It act differently from directly executing the original VLC program. Why?

**My question is:**

1. What's different between executing VLC executable from Terminal and executing a symlink of VLC from Terminal ?
2. Is that correct to build a symlink for an executable? If yes, how can I make it?
3. Is there any difference between executing program from Terminal and executing it by double clicking  ?

**File Path:**

- VLC program is located at: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC
- I build a symlink at: /usr/local/bin

---

**What I've tried:**

- I built a symlink and run it from Terminal, failed to open.
- I tried to build symlink in the same directory of VLC but it still doesn't work.
- I tried to build a hard link to it, and it doesn't work as well.
- I double click the symlink by mouse and it work just fine !!!
- I have tried the alias command and it works.

---

**The result show in my Terminal:**

Symlink created by:

```
cmd-> ln -s /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC /usr/local/bin/vlc
```

Execute VLC program directly from Terminal, the VLC UI show up and work just fine:

```
cmd-> /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC
VLC media player 3.0.11.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11.1-0-g52483f3ca2)
[00007fceeff062d0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007fceefd74790] main playlist: playlist is empty
```

Execute the symlink I have created, however the VLC UI doesn't show up and it stop:

```
cmd-> /usr/local/bin/vlc
VLC media player 3.0.11.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11.1-0-g52483f3ca2)
```